# Can't start MariaDB after a system crash

Tags: mariadb

`systemctl status mariadb-server` gives me the following error message. What should I do? Using systemd networking and tried adding `ProtectHome=false` and `ProtectSystem=off` to conf file as suggested but to no avail.

```
 mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11.6 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-03-18 12:01:24 UTC; 14s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 23247 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 23249 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 23254 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_ST>
    Process: 23264 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 23275 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 23277 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 23264 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 90ms

Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240318 12:01:24
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 47024; transaction id 18
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 mariadbd[23264]: 2024-03-18 12:01:24 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 18 12:01:24 ns533923 systemd[1]: Failed to start mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.11.6 database server.
```

Comment: something is very wrong with your system start, it shuts down the server

Comment: Are you using Galera? Does you MariaDB error log (assuming you have one ...) have any more information than what systemd reveals here? If you don't have an error log, you can add one to your configuration and then try to start the mariadb service again.

Comment: Just use `journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 50` to get the complete logs from startup to shutdown. The end bit looks like a normal shutdown. The only thing that filed is `/etc/mysql/debian-start` on post shutdown. Are credentials in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf wrong or have your removed the `unix_socket` auth on your root user? [ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security)